# 404 error for PNG image in IIS

Tags: tomcat, iis, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have a site hosted on server `ABC` running on `5000` port. I have another site hosted on `XYZ` server running on port `6000`. when you hit `http://ABC:5000/mysite` url, it redirects to `http://XYZ:6000`. All this is working fine.

On ABC server's virtual directory I have `img` folder, under which I have two png images. when I hit `http://XYZ:6000`, everything works fine. But when the request originates from `ABC` server (which then gets redirected to `XYZ` server), system us giving 404 error for these images. Please see the below image. The type of these two images are coming as `'text/html'`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIS returns 404 for any unknown file types, i.e. those that don't have MIME-types. Add png to the IIS mime types.